# How can I share a Google Apps Script with my colleagues?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-marketplace

I created a custom Google Sheets add-on using the Script Editor.

Now I want to make the add-on accessible while looking at other workbooks and I want to share it with my colleagues so that they can use it as well - I am not interested and have no need of sharing it to the app-store. What I am finding is that I can 'share' it with them while in the Google Apps Script home area and that it becomes visible in their Google Apps Script area under 'Shared with me', but I don't know how to turn turn it on for them to actually use in a workbook. I only need 2 other people to have access.

Comment: Have you tried Libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next step for you would be to [Publishing that Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) so you can share it with friends or colleagues.

> Publishing add-ons allows them to be used by other users in their own
>   documents. Public add-ons require a review before publication,
>   although if you are a member of a private G Suite domain, you can
>   publish just for users within your domain without a review. You can
>   also [publish an add-on for domain-wide
>   installation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide),
>   which lets a domain admins find, authorize and install your add-on on
>   behalf of all users within their domain.

Comment: This publication process is completely over the top for sharing with 2 colleagues - I guess I'll just have to stick to copy-paste sharing...

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you are able to share the script but don't know how to test it as an add-on for sheet, so I'll only write how to test it as add-on, let me know if you need more help.

### Create a test configuration

1. If you do not have one already, create a Sheet, Doc or Form to test the add-on with. If desired, format and fill the doc with data that the add-on will be operating on.
2. Open the script project containing your add-on in the script editor.
3. (Optional) You may wish to save a version of your project by selecting File > Manage versions, then Save New Version. Close the Manage Versions dialog.
4. Select Run > Test as add-on.
5. In the Select version box, choose a code version or select "Test with latest code".
6. In the Installation Config box, select the initial authorization state for the test.
7. Click the Select Doc button. This will bring up a file select dialog. Find the test Sheet, Doc or Form you want to test the add-on on, click it, and then click Select to close the dialog.
8. Click Save to save the test configuration.

### Run a test configuration

1. Open the script project containing your add-on in the script editor.
2. Select Run > Test as add-on.
3. Under Execute Saved Test, find the test to execute and select it. Click Test.

**I have taken the text from this documentation** you should go through these for reference too.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/test#create_a_test_configuration

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/test#run_a_test_configuration

Comment: Hi there, thanks for copying that info from Google. I did read tat guide actually but it doesn't quite answer my question. I don't need to test my script anymore, I need to share it with my colleagues so that they can use it. Thanks.

Comment: You can share by adding your colleagues in share dialog box, what issue are you facing now ?

Comment: They can see the script in their Google Apps Script environment but they cannot access those scripts to use them in an actual workbook

Comment: I think, they need to Publish as test add-on to test.